# capybara rspec matcher equivalent of response.should have_selector "form", :action => some_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, capybara

Is there a matcher in capybara that will check for the presence of a form with a particular action? I'd like to be able to say something like this:

page.should have_form :action => some_action

It looks like the [rspec-html-matchers](https://github.com/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers) gem does what I need, and more, but I find it strange that Capybara rspec matchers wouldn't provide something like it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the xpath node matcher:

```
has_xpath?("//form[@action='/some_action']")
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_xpath%3F-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the regular matchers e.g. `have_css()`

```
have_css("form[action='/users/new']")
```